# No USB 3.0 functionality

Tags: drivers, usb, lenovo, motherboard

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I came to it because I had a pretty old, but still very powerful tower that completely failed in Windows and wouldn't even recognize the hard drives plugged directly into the motherboard in the bios. Through some luck and black magic I was able to revive it with Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Once revived I remembered that the usb 3.0 ports (2 front, 2 back) never worked and they still don't. Upon checking, the front ports are properly connected to the motherboard and the rear two are hard wired onto it.

When I try lsusb -v I only see USB 2.0 and 2.1 devices. When I checked the PCI devices, the only USB related things I saw were two "...chipset USB2 Enhanced host controller #...". Lots of PCI bridges and things that I'm not familiar with. Plugging a USB 2.0 device into the 3.0 port doesn't populate any drive, so their not even functioning as usb 2.0 ports.

So, drivers seems like the most common answer when I search (though I'm still not clear on how to manage that), but I'm not sure if that's the solution since I can't even find USB 3.0 anywhere in the system.

Here are the system stats, as far as I know:

- Lenovo ThinkStation D30
- BIOS: A3KT36AUS (2014)
- Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1660 v2 3.7
- Motherboard: LGA2011-0 Dual socket (I think this it right, but I'm not totally sure... it's printed on the mb, I'm just not sure if that's the right identifier to use).
- Is there any other info that would be helpful?

I searched the forums before posting, as well as google and some longtime ubuntu friends, but so far can't find anything, perhaps because this isn't an ubuntu problem, it's a lenovo one. Nevertheless, if anyone has any insight, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: USB 3.0 has been included in the Linux Kernel for many, many years, so working hardware will be automatically detected, configured, and made available to you. Since it's not being detected, the most likely culprit is faulty or nonstandard hardware.

Comment: Looks like there are hardware problems, which is not something Ubuntu can solve. Problems experienced with Windows seem to corroborate that.

Comment: https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/workstations/thinkstation/d-series/d30/ says there are only 2 USB 3.0 ports on the rear. If you are expecting the front ports to be 3.0, they are not.

Answer (score 3):

First, check your BIOS for a USB setting. It may have choices like "legacy", or "compatibility", or "USB 3 enable". Adjust as required.

Second, your BIOS is very old. You have version A3KT36AUS, from 2014.

The current BIOS is version A3KT68A, from Feb 25, 2020.

**Note**: Make sure to perform important data backups before flashing a new BIOS.

**Note**: Make sure that the web site covers your specific model D30. The BIOS update at the links given below covers D30 (type 4353, 4354).

Download the new version [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035725), or [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/workstations/thinkstation-d-series-workstations/thinkstation-d30/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

Comment: This sounds like it's probably the right course to take, the problem is that I can't get into the BIOS. This isn't an autoboot issue... I'm able to get to the blue menu where it prompts me to press F1 for BIOS, but when I do it goes to a black screen with a white underscore, then the underscore disappears and I'm just left with a black screen until I force a restart. I can't figure out any way to update with BIOS without being in the BIOS, but again, I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Yup, you have a BIOS issue. Can you boot to ANYTHING right now? At the links that I gave, there are multiple ways to upgrade the BIOS... the DVD .iso is probably the most reliable. Try this... unplug the machine from AC, press the power switch for 10 seconds, remove the quarter-size battery from the motherboard, press the power switch for another 10 seconds, let the machine sit for 30 mintues, replace the battery, and see if you can get into the BIOS now. Report back.

Comment: @Jay Oops, I forgot your @ tag on my previous comment. Please check it out. Otherwise, what's the status right now?

Comment: @Jay Status please...

Comment: @Jay Status please...

Comment: @Jay Status please... fourth request.